# Unexpected data return from API using HTTPResponseMesssage

Tags: c#, httpresponse, httpresponsemessage

I have this problem where in my Response Body returns data that I did not want to include and my data that I want to return was not included in there. I try this using Swagger v1.0

**Data Returned**

```
{
 "version": {
    "major": 1,
    "minor": 1,
    "build": -1,
    "revision": -1,
    "majorRevision": -1,
    "minorRevision": -1
  },
  "content": {
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Content-Type",
        "value": [
          "application/json"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "statusCode": 200,
  "reasonPhrase": "OK",
  "headers": [],
  "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

**Expected Return**

[image]

Here is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetStudent(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var student = _studentService.Find(id);
            return ModelHelper.ComposeResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, student);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exceptionMessage = ModelHelper.GetErrors(ex, _mailService);
            ModelState.AddModelError(new ValidationResult(exceptionMessage));
        }
        return ModelHelper.ComposeResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelHelper.GetModelStateErrors(ModelState));
    }
```

**Helper Code**

```
 public static HttpResponseMessage ComposeResponse(HttpStatusCode statusCode, object responseData)
        {
            var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseData);
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = statusCode,
                Content = new StringContent(jsonResponse, Encoding.UTF8, Constants.Common.ApplicationJson)
            };

            resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(Constants.Common.ApplicationJson);

            return resp;
        }
```

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET MVC project or an ASP.NET MVC Core project? HttpResponseMessage is a Web API type, which MVC doesn't support directly.

Comment: @CodeCaster MVC Core project sir

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could make this using the CreateResponse function. This will create a json output from the object that you passed into the CreateResponse function.

Response will look like this.

> {"Stud_id":1,"Stud_name":"test"}

```
    public class StudentObject
    {
        public int Stud_id { get; set; }
        public string Stud_name { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetStudent(int id)
    {
        StudentObject studentObject = new StudentObject
        {
            Stud_id = 1,
            Stud_name = "test"
        };
        return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, studentObject);
    }
```

Comment: What is CreateResponse? i got an error on it. is this an extenstion?